# Finding the path of resource folder?

Tags: iphone

Is there any way (programmatically) that i can find the location of "Resource" folder. I want to create a new file in it at run time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get path to resource folder use:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
```

However you won't be able to write anything there in run-time. New files should be saved to 1 of the following directories (depending of their usage):

1. Documents directory - persists between app launches and backuped by iTunes

   ```
   NSString* docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
                  (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
   ```
2. Caches directory - persists between app launches but not backuped by iTunes - you should place there files that can be easily restored by your program to improve device backup time

   ```
   NSString* cachesPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
                  (NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
   ```
3. Temporary directory - may not persist between app launches

   ```
   NSString* tempPath = NSTemporaryDirectory();
   ```